# How to deserialize without fileinputstream

Tags: java, web-services, serialization, navision

How to deserialize an `Object` without file input.

I have got this:

```
List<Serializable> objs = holder.value.getContent();
```

The list is filled with 10 serialized objects.

How to deserialize them? Since `ObjectInputStream` expects an `FileInputStream` parameter and not an serialized object.

I am sure there must be a way to deserialize and object without a `FileInputStream`.

(The holder is a respons from a CodeUnit function from navision 2013)

Answer (score 2):

If they are really `Serializable` instances in that list, then you don't need to deserialize them. It would only be if they were a `byte[]` or `InputStream`, typically, that would mean they were still serialized.

So just cast them to what you expect them to be.

Answer (score 0):

It expects `InputStream` and it's not mandatory to use `FileInputStream`

```
InputStream is;
ObjectInputStream in;
Object obj;
in = new ObjectInputStream(is);
obj = in.readObject();
in.close();
```